# Cross platform Native C++ DLL in Unity builds but fails at runtime

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, dll

I am currently working on creating a native, unmanaged C++ DLL for a Unity project. The DLL uses sockets, and I need it to be cross-platform with Unix based systems.

Clearly I need to use [WinSock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/using-winsock) when on a Windows platform, and [POSIX](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) sockets when on something like Linux.

The Windows build runs fine from Unity with no problems. I can also *build* to Linux, but I get runtime errors when I actually try and use the Linux application. I *think* that this is because the DLL is linked at runtime, and the pre-processor checks I have for different platforms in my C++ code are not actually being re-compiled.

I know that DLL's are Windows proprietary, so there has to be something going on where Unity can actually build with the DLL to Linux in the first place, right? Or is it just not giving me linker errors because I am compiling in a Windows environment, and it doesn't know any better?

My thoughts are that I am going to need to build more than one DLL for my different target platforms. Then check which one to use in C# with some pre-precessor checks.
My problem with that is that it is going to make my code a bit of a mess, and I was hoping to abstract the platform checking stuff to C++ so that others can use this DLL more easily.

If anyone has any insight on a direction to move forward in, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: So what's the error message? All links are done at runtime, Windows and Linux, but on Windows, you get fully linked files, on Linux you may omit the check. You can add link flags to make sure you have everything.

Comment: Also, are you using the same version of Unity on both Windows and Linux? They change the plugin interface periodically. It's not clear whether this is really a loading error, initialization or if the error is happening in your code.